# Left Outer Join in sql query

Tags: mysql, sql, database, group-by, outer-join

The database:

```
EMPLOYEE (fname, minit, lname, ssn, birthdate, address, sex, salary, superssn, dno)     KEY: ssn
DEPARTMENT (dname, dnumber, mgrssn, mgrstartdate)               KEY: dnumber.
PROJECT  (pname, pnumber, plocation, dnum)                          KEY: pnumber.
WORKS_ON (essn, pno, hours)                                         KEY: (essn, pno)
DEPENDENT  (essn, dependent-name, sex, bdate, relationship)             KEY: (essn, dependent-name)
```

I want to use `left outer join` and `group by` to...
Find the last name and SSN of those managers who work on 3 or more projects and who are not located in Cleveland.

Here is what I have so far:

```
select Lname
  from Employee e outer join Department d
where (e.ssn = d.mgrssn) 
   and  ssn NOT in (
                      select  w.essn
                       from   works_on w outer join Project p
                      where w.pno = p.pnumber
                          and  p.plocation = 'Cleveland'
                      group by w.essn
                      having count(*) >= 3
                     )
```

Did I do it right using `left outer join` and `group by`? Should I divide this code into two parts, like loops?

Comment: `outer join` is not a sql join type.  There is `LEFT outer join` and `RIGHT outer join` and `FULL outer join`.  In addition, all these would expect an `on` clause (or `using` clause) afterwards.

Comment: I'm sorry I meant left outer join, can you please write an answer?

Comment: I promise I will accept, really lost here

Comment: using left outer join

Comment: So if project is on Cleveland the Employee is located in Cleveland?

Comment: @ juan carlos oropeza yeah thats only database I have

Comment: what is your rdbms? Mysql, Sql server, Posgres, Oracle?

Comment: mysql, I' just trying to practice writing this in an exam, hope you can help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select `JOIN`  find all project for the employee

First `HAVING` tell you this user doesnt have project in `'Cleveland'`

Second `HAVING` tell you this user has 3 project or more

.

```
SELECT e.Lname, e.ssn
FROM Employee e   
JOIN works_on w
  ON e.ssn = w.essn
JOIN Project p
  ON w.pno = p.pnumber
GROUP BY e.ssn
HAVING 
     SUM(CASE WHEN p.plocation = 'Cleveland' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0
AND  COUNT(*) >= 3
```